# ArrayList returns same element for every index

Tags: java

I suspect that the value being returned is the last one I have added to my arraylist.

I've got a class `Game` where the following function gets executed...

```
    public List<M> compute() throws CloneNotSupportedException{
    G chil = (G) this.clone();
    List<Move> Pm = new ArrayList<M>();
            Point p;

       for(/*condition*/){
                //p is defined up here.basically loops through all possible values of p.
            M m = pud.genM(chil, p);
            Pm.add(m);
        }
       return Pmoves;
}
```

The strange thing is I'm doing a print on the values being returned for `m` and they are as expected (different) but when I loop through the List that has been created each and every element is equal to the last element that was added. It appears that this last to be added element is overriding all previous children...

The variable `pud` is of type `User`. The function being called is...

```
public M genM(GameState g, boardPoint p){
    M m; // a move
    for(/*condition*/){
        m = new M(/*parameters*/);
        return m;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I've simplified this class down a fair bit, there's some if else conditions and an additional for loop but I took them out of this example because they're kind of messy and most likely irrelevant.

The object `M` is defined as...

```
    public M(String type, Point fPos, Point tPos, String input, G g){
    this.type = type;
    this.toPos = toPos;
    this.fromPos = fromPos;
    this.uInput = uInput;
    result = new G(g);
            //value of G gets edited here.
}
```

Comment: Can you write a self contained program which reproduces the problem?  Write a simple program which shows the issue and keep simplifying it until you can't show the problem.

Comment: You're calling `genM` in the sample code, but then you've shown `genMenMoves` - are they meant to be the same method? (I really hope your names are clearer in your actual code...)

Comment: Those are some of the most cryptic class and method names I've seen in a long time!

Comment: try to debug step-by-step. Perhaps Your genM function has the same incoming parameters. I have not see an error in your code. Try to limit your array to 3 elements and investigate - are they similar?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite difficult to understand what's going on in the code, since the snippets are non-compilable and the names rather cryptic, but I'll have a go...

The `return` statement you have in the `for` loop below looks highly suspect:

```
public M genM(GameState g, boardPoint p){
    M m; // a move
    for(/*condition*/){
        m = new M(/*parameters*/);
        return m;
    }
    return null;
}
```

If it's really an unconditional `return` out of a `for` loop, then the loop will run for at most one iteration.

This could be a red herring, but again, it's hard to be sure based on the code you've shown us.

Comment: That would be my guess as well. That you are somehow returning the same element over and over again rather than returning the new element.

Answer (score 0):

You have removed some related code and names types does not really match but i think you have some problem with the object you call as either P or G.

Possibly:

You are cloning G object once and then, in the for loop, operating on the same G object thus affecting all values inside the list.

Basicly, you are changing some values of G and adding it to list several times. At the end all object are same as you are working on same G object.